# Server to Server transfer

Tags: windows, ftp, data-transfer, web-hosting

I am currently trying to migrate my website from one host to a newer one. What FTP client allows direct server to server transfer without me physically downloading the files to my computer.

Any other means of doing the same without the use of an FTP client? Or let me rephrase that. Is there a better way of doing server to server transfer of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for a client that supports "FXP". If supported by the server, this allows FTP-to-FTP connections without passing through the client.

Comment: do you know of any such client? I don't mind it being paid too..

Comment: Nope, sorry. I usually ssh in and rsync the files over.

Comment: FXP is the best way:  FlashFXP (http://www.flashfxp.com/) will do this for you.

Comment: do you have a reason why it is "best"...does it offer encryption for files in transit or something?(sarcasm on the encryption part)

Answer (score 2):

ssh from one server to the other and use scp

on windows you can use putty to connect to the server you want to copy from like so: http://www.jfitz.com/tips/putty_config.html

then typing:

```
ssh username@host_ip_to_be_copied_to
#enter password when prompted
scp username@host_ip_to_be_copied_from:path_to_be_copied_from
#enter password when prompted
#wait until complete
```

done

Comment: @aking1012 : sounds like greek and latin to me, could you elaborate and by the way I'm using shared hosting accounts.

Comment: what host OS are you using? (your computer)

Comment: I use Windows 7 on my computer, and I have 2 linux shared hosting accounts.

Comment: edited to make it a bit more clear...this is a command line solution

Comment: ssh to the first server isn't really REQUIRED but it does make sure that you have the right passwords/usernames for both ssh accounts and that ssh is enabled/not firewalled

Comment: Note that shared hosting doesn't always provide SSH access; you'll need to verify with both sides first.

Comment: yepper, that's why i had ssh from one server to the other and use scp as the first line and use putty to connect to the server you want to copy from...i think these steps account for ssh on both hosts