# Move files from one server directly to another server without writing to PC disk

Tags: linux, vmware, ftp, lftp

Forgive me if I word this Poorly.

I'm working with a Linux desktop and several ESXi hosts.  Lets name my desktop Desk-1 and the ESXi hosts ESXi-1 and ESXi-2 for simplicity's sake.  I'd like to move files from ESXi-1 to ESXi-2.  I can use lftp to gain access to each host and upload/download files to/from Desk-1 and Desk-2 without issue.  Is there a way to move the files from ESXi-1 directly to ESXi-2 without first writing the files to Desk-1.  I'm open to using any Linux based solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server to Server transfer](http://superuser.com/questions/214277/server-to-server-transfer)

Comment: Would it be possible to `ssh` to ESXi-1 and do `scp` from there? That would eliminate the intermediate bandwidth problem from @Zoredache's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both servers are running ESXi you could use `scp -3` option to transfer from one server to another without the files being stored on the intermediate system.  The bandwidth of the intermediate system will still be used though.

Answer (score 0):

If your ftp server supports FXP, ie, Server to Server File Transfers, you could use an FXP compliant ftp client to initiate the server-to-server file transfer. This would let the client tell server A to send a file to server B.

Not too many servers support this, primarily because you have one server process trying to open a direct connection to the other server process, and many servers prevent this for security reasons.

Hope that helps!